# No success with the "survIDINRI" package. Error message: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have been trying unsuccessfully to do Net Reclassification Index (NRI) and Integrated Discrimination Improvement (IDI) using the packages “PredictABEL” and “survIDINRI”.

Here I post the code I have been using for the “survIDINRI” one. The idea is to see whether the variable “glst_new” (or gcst_new, grst_new) can improve classification of risk done by the variable “lvef_low”. Let me know if you need any more information about the variables.

I get the following error message:

Error in unoecdf(cc, pdiff[cont], PTB.Vi[cont]) :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)

Below the code:

```
D<- select(ICI_strain_cases, redcap_id, admission_fu_event, cvdeath_vf_shock_chb_arr,
            age_ici, sex___1, lvef_low, glst_new, gcst_new, grst_new)

D$cvdeath_vf_shock_chb_arr=as.numeric(D$cvdeath_vf_shock_chb_arr==1)
D=D[!is.na(apply(D,1,mean)),] ; dim(D)
mydata=D[1:75,]
t0=365
indata=select(mydata, admission_fu_event, cvdeath_vf_shock_chb_arr)
indata1=select(mydata, redcap_id:lvef_low)
indata0=select(mydata, redcap_id:sex___1, glst_new)
covs1=as.matrix(indata1[,c(-1, -2, -3)])
covs0=as.matrix(indata0[,c(-1, -2, -3)])

IDI.INF(indata, covs0, covs1, t0, npert = 300, npert.rand = NULL, seed1 = NULL, alpha = 0.05)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Usually this arises because there are NAs, NaNs, Infs or -Infs in the data. You can check with `is.na( )`, `is.nan( )` and `is.infinite( )`, e.g. `any(is.na(indata))`.

Comment: Thank you slamballais.  I ran: any(is.na(indata)) and got [1] FALSE. The original dataset "ICI_strain_cases" does have missing data, but the setting up of "indata" excludes all NAs ## here: D=D[!is.na(apply(D,1,mean)),] ; dim(D)
mydata=D[1:75,] ## Would you have any other suggestion? Thank you very much for the help.